# How can I solve 500 error at store request form laravel api, when I try to save file to storage/images folder

Tags: laravel, api, file-upload

In a laravel api I am creating I managed to create a crud system. My first, being new to Laravel and Vue..

I can add and edit image-paths to the database, but when I try to actually save the image to the storage folder I keep getting errors.

```
    Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException: Image source not readable in file D:\laravel\ijsbreker_memory\vendor\intervention\image\src\Intervention\Image\AbstractDecoder.php on line 351
```

The controller looks like:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

        logger($request->all());
        //validate data first
        $request->validate([
            'description'=> 'required'
        ]);
        
        $card = $request->all();
       
        if ($request->hasFile('imagefile')){
        
           // $this->validate($request, ['picture' => 'max:2000'], [__('Maximum file size of 2MB allowed')]);
           
            
            
            $image = $request->file('picture'); //file_picture_input  is naam van file inputveld in het formulier, de naam die de request aan de file geeft
            $image_name = strval(time().Str::random(5)).'.png'; //.$image->extension; // voor de zekerheid string van maken..
          
            $path = asset('storage/images/'.$image_name);

           //   SYSTEM WORKS WHEN FOLLOWING FOUR LINES ARE COMMENTED OUT

            $img = Image::make($image);
            $img->resize(300, 300, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($path); 
           
            $card['picture'] = $path;

        }
        else {
            $card['picture'] = 'img/profile/default_avatar.png';
        }
    
        //create a post
        return Card::create($card);
    }
```

Does anyone see where I make my (probably silly) mistake?

Comment: Server error 500 is logged in error.log file so make sure to check that one...

Comment: In the apache errorlog in XAMP (localhost) I have no recent errors... The error in the console reads: "app.js:22182 POST http://localhost:8000/api/cards 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: `Image::make($request->file('picture')->getRealPath())` Try like this.

Comment: also I just found out that when I use  if ($request->hasFile('imagefile')){
        
           // $this->validate($request, ['picture' => 'max:2000'], [__('Maximum file size of 2MB allowed')]);
            
            $image = $request->file('picture'); 
            $image_name = strval(time().Str::random(5)).$image->extension();

I get the 500 error as well

Comment: $img = Image::make($request->file('picture')->getRealPath())  gives same error 500

Comment: it seems that, when I start using IMAGE the errors begin. I have use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

Comment: In laravel log:  local.ERROR: Call to a member function getRealPath() on null {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function getRealPath() on null

Comment: tested a bit more, as soon as I use $img = Image::make($image), in my laravel api-controller,  the 500 error pops up in the vue calling the api.